# Error 'no coinciden los tipos' en VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hola sucede que estoy consumiendo una API de la cual me dan el URL a la cual le debo agregar unos parámetros para que me arroje un resultado.

Esta API me retorna un JSON el cual debo cargar en a una tabla en Excel

Pero me tira el error **'Error 6 en tiempo de ejecución, desbordamiento'** el cual es en el valor id **al poner un numero mayor a 32767**([como dice aqui](https://www.excel-avanzado.com/28768/integer-en-vba.html)), leí que debo cambiarlo de integer a long pero ahora me muestra el error **'no coinciden los tipos'** en esta linea: *Set items = jp("items")*

Aqui mi codigo:

```html
Option Explicit

Sub TestTablas()
    Dim Tablas As QueryTable
    Dim url As String
    Dim id As Long
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim endDate As String

    Dim req As Object
    Dim strjson As String
    Dim jp As Object
    Dim dict
    Dim subdict
    Dim subsubdict
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim roleJson As String
    Dim jpRoles As Object
    Dim items
    Dim itemsId
    Dim attr
    Dim itemattr
    
    id = Hoja10.Range("C2")
    startDate = Format(Hoja10.Range("C3"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    endDate = Format(Hoja10.Range("C4"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    url = "https://xxx.yyy.com/api/zzz?id=" & id& "&startDate=" & startDate & "&endDate=" & endDate & "&timezone=-6"
        
    Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    req.Open "GET", url, False
    req.Send
    
    Set jp = JsonConverter.ParseJson(req.ResponseText)
    Set items = jp("items")
    
    roleJson = req.ResponseText
    Set jpRoles = JsonConverter.ParseJson(roleJson)
    Set items = jpRoles("items")
    
    i = 7
    For Each itemsId In items
        For Each attr In itemsId
           ' Debug.Print attr
            'Debug.Print itemsId(attr)
            
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 1).Value = itemsId("name")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 2).Value = itemsId("Position")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 3).Value = itemsId("positionDate")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 4).Value = itemsId("latitude")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 5).Value = itemsId("longitude")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 6).Value = itemsId("Orientation")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 7).Value = itemsId("speed")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 8).Value = itemsId("receiptDate")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 9).Value = itemsId("notification")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 10).Value = itemsId("kilometers")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 11).Value = itemsId("unitVoltage")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 12).Value = itemsId("gpsVoltage")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 13).Value = itemsId("satellites")
            
        Next attr
         i = i + 1
    Next itemsId
    
End Sub
```

Comment: No has definido el tipo de datos de `items`, con lo cual se está creando como Variant. No puedo probarlo ahora, pero creo que `jp` debería ser de tipo `Dictionary` y `items` debería ser de tipo `string`, así que la línea al no ser un objeto no necesita el `set`. Debería avanzar con `items = jpRoles("items")`